# Info dialog is not shown for an ajax button/link

Tags: primefaces

I am using a p:commandlink to do save for the top panel in m =y page. but since its an ajax call am not getting the info dialog confirming save. Can anyone suggest a solution.

I would also like to know if its possible to call a dialog from a backing bean class..

Answer (score 1):

You can call a dialog from a backing bean. Set the widgetVar attributte for you dialog an then in backing bean method you can call:
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("widgetName.show()")`.

For the problem with commandLink you must add your code in post.

Comment: `<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Send To Test Failed"    widgetVar="sendToTestValidationDialog"   rendered="#{viewOrModifyMedicalRuleBean.versionNonMatchingRules != null || viewOrModifyMedicalRuleBean.versionNonMatchingRules != ''}"  modal="true" height="100">                <h:outputText value="The following rules s are not in  sync'" />  <h:outputText   value="#{viewOrModifyMedicalRuleBean.versionNonMatchingRules}" / <p:commandButton value="Ok" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:90px;" /> </p:dialog>'

Comment: I tried that am getting a null pointer am not sure why.. The code above.. i tried that the dialog comes but does not persist just comes like a flash and goes.

Comment: I also tried calling the above dailog using a script but it does not persist

Comment: Why don't you use Firebug. That's how you can see the error in javascript. Also when you are providing your code you should formati it in the proper way. I suppose that you have problem in your `rendered` attributte. My second question: Is your `p:dialog` inculded in a h:form? BEcause it should be. If not then you should put `<h:form>` inside your dialog

Comment: Hi i used the request.getcontext.execute method, I think the dialog is coming but for some reason the page gets refreshed. Does anyone know why this happens..